# What should I cite for the Poincaré conjecture?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, 3-manifolds, citations

I'm writing a paper that, rather unexpectedly, needs the Poincaré conjecture for one of the results. (The paper has almost nothing to do with differential geometry!)

The conjecture was famously proved at the beginning of the century by Perelman, in a series of three papers. Unfortunately, I'm not a differential geometer, and I fear that if I read his papers I won't understand anything or be able to pinpoint in which one the conjecture is solved.

I'm sure that if I just write "the Poincaré conjecture, due to Perelman" in my paper everybody will understand what I'm talking about. But it still feels "normal" to cite something. So: what should I cite? Nothing? One of the three papers? All three of them? Something else?

Comment: Out of curiosity - why does the conjecture pop up?

Comment: @Arrow I have a proof that works for all closed simply connected manifolds of dimension at least 4, and the proposition is obvious for spheres for other reasons.

Comment: Terminology: I think you are citing the *proof* of the Poincare conjecture, not the conjecture itself.

Comment: @post.as.a.guest, that doesn't seem to be the case at all.  It appears that the OP wants to assert that his theorem is true for all simply connected manifolds, and needs the fact that every closed, simply connected 3-manifold is a sphere.  That is exactly the *statement* of the Poincaré conjecture.

Comment: OK, if you are only using the statement of the conjecture (but not the proof) then shouldn't you cite Poincaré's paper? But I must admit, I don't see why you only need the statement of a conjecture to get his conclusion unconditionally. I guess it comes down to: would you say "By the Poincaré conjecture we know that every CSC3M is a sphere", or "By the proof of the Poincaré conjecture, we know that every CSC3M is a sphere." Another example of this (in algebraic geometry) is "We know X by the Weil conjectures", when really you mean "We know X by Deligne's proof of the Weil conjectures", no?

Comment: In any event "the Poincaré conjecture, due to Perelman" (as the OP text suggests) is a dubious linguistic construction/shorthand, as the Poincaré conjecture as such is due to Poincaré, with the proof of it being due to Perelman (and others, if you wish).

Comment: @post.as.a.guest: right, it's an unfortunate quirk that even once a conjecture is proven, it can continue to be known by the now-inadequate title it has borne. "The Poincaré Conjecture" is, unfortunately, used here as the name of the *theorem* proved by Perelman. If it was called "Perelman's Theorem" then we wouldn't have this fuss about whether one says, "we know this by PT" or "we know this by the proof of PT". The former alone would be sufficient to imply we're taken that it's proven.

Comment: You could also use a phrase similar to "Perelman's affirmative proof of the Poincaré Conjecture [Perelman1,Perelman2, see also Morgan--Tian]."

Comment: Yes, that's the way, e.g., the Mordell conjecture is typically referred to, something like: "Faltings' theorem, né Mordell Conjecture". I agree with SteveJessop that prominent conjectures often quirkily retains such monikers even after being proven. I guess PC is currently so famous that it can't matter, but I've seen talks where the speaker refers to something being true by "the Weil conjectures" where I'd guess less than half the audience knows this is a theorem. The Bieberbach conjecture (de Branges's theorem) is another example, Catalan/Mihăilescu, Kepler/Hales/Flyspeck...

Comment: Instead of phrases like "by the Poincare conjecture [Perelman03]...", you can write "by the validity of the  Poincare conjecture [Perelman03]".

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I think it is customary to cite at least the first two papers ("The entropy formula for the Ricci flow and its geometric applications" and "Ricci flow with surgery on three-manifolds"). See [this](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/2009-137-06/S0002-9939-09-09792-5/) for an example. Together they imply the full geometrization conjecture.

The shortest proof of "just Poincare" involves the third paper, but I guess that's beyod the point.

Comment: I would also consider citing the monographs of Morgan--Tian and Kleiner--Lott.

Comment: Cite the Perelman papers directly and in parentheses, say "also, see..." and cite the other expositions of the proof.